# PyQt5: Positioning widgets

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Code: http://pastebin.com/xKuabn8b

I am creating a gui in python QT and have a problem where I cant position my label properly because Im using a grid layout. If you see my code and run it, youll see that the "LP" label is to the side when in fact, I want it next to my radioButton. I have 3 other radio buttons I want adding once I figure out whats the best way to place them along with there labels next to them.

I have been researching how to use a QHBoxLayout to maybe fix the issue but it just positions it in the middle of my gui. Would I need to use absolute positioning to line it up or is there a way to use my GridLayout I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefered solution: set the label directly to the radio button as a parameter in the constructor.

Solution 2: use addStretch method from QHBoxLayout

Comment: how do I add my label as a parameter to my radiobutton? Ive tried passing it like so: self.lpRadioButton = QRadioButton(lpLabel) but it throws me an error

Comment: As string: self.lpRadioButton = QRadioButton("LP")  and delete lpLabel from the code.

Comment: Ah right, thanks. I didnt know you could add strings to it. Ive been trying to use labels. Ive just tried adding another button using the same method but the spacing isnt what Id like with the grid layout. Id like the radio buttons to be a little closer. If I want them closer, would I need to use the addStretch like you said?

Comment: Made a QBoxLayout and added a stretch of 5 doing: self.radiobuttonLayout.addStretch(5) and It didnt change anything. How would changing the stretch help me move them down? I thought stretch just pushed them to the right or left?

Comment: Can you post the updated code, I might not understand the last question corectly. Any way stretch only pushes left or right in case of QHBoxLayout.

Comment: Yeah sure: http://pastebin.com/FsheAF6T   if stretch only moves left and right, thats not what I need. Are you able to run the code? youll see that right now, the buttons are in the middle, to the right when I want to slot them under year and genre.

Comment: I cannot run the code right now. But you could use addLayout method from the grid layout, with rowSpan and columnSpan. See doc: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html